# harmon.ie error with attachments "Failed to replace one or more"

Tags: harmon.ie

We have a user running Outlook 2013 with Harmon.IE version 4.1.1.3322

When they try to forward an email with multiple attachments (one each of .doc, .pdf and .ics) they get an error message stating,

Failed to replace one more more attachments with links. If you try to send the message again the remaining attachments will not be replaced with links.

Is there any known issues with Harmon.ie and Outlook 2013? Or is that a problem with the file type? (That said I am running the same setup and it worked fine for me)

Answer (score 0):

Please download and install our latest version 4.6 from our web site then check again.

---- Jean